# matching two matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have two matrices `p`

```
p =
 1     3     6     7     3     6
 8     5    10    10    10     4
 5     4     8     9     1     7
 5     5     5     3     8     9
 9     3     5     4     3     1
 3     3     9    10     4     1
```

then  after sorting the columns of matrix `p` into ascending order

```
y =  
 1     3     5     3     1     1
 3     3     5     4     3     1
 5     3     6     7     3     4
 5     4     8     9     4     6
 8     5     9    10     8     7
 9     5    10    10    10     9
```

I want to know, given a value from `y`, what its row was in `p`

ex: the value 3 which is in matrix `p` located in row 6 column 1

then after sorting it located in matrix `y` in row 2 column 1

So I want at the end the values after sorting in matrix `y`, where it was originally in matrix `p`

Comment: What happens if you have duplicate values in the column? How are you sorting the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use second output of `sort`:

```
[y ind] = sort(p);
```

Your desired result (original row of each value) is in matrix `ind`.

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) command returns a second value which can be used to index into the original array or matrix. From the [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) documentation:

```
[Y,I] = sort(X,DIM,MODE) also returns an index matrix I.
If X is a vector, then Y = X(I).  
If X is an m-by-n matrix and DIM=1, then
    for j = 1:n, Y(:,j) = X(I(:,j),j); end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand exactly what you want.

I will give you my code that i write now, it is not optimal but you can optimize it or i can work with you in order to get the better code..

P and y have the same size.

```
    [n,m]=size(p);

    for L=1:m
    i=1;
    temp=y(i,L);
    while(i<=n)
    if(temp==y(i,L))
    % So it is present in case i of p
    disp(['It is present in line' num2str(i) ' of p']);

    end
    i=i+1;
    end
    end
```

Voilà!!